# How to create Google App Engine Backend Thread?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm new in App Engine. I want to create guess words game with App Engine. So, I need to create one instance of main channel thread that listen to answer from clients and sending response and new question every periode of time.

**Illustration**

[image: Illustration]

(1) The server thread send message to the clients

(2) Sleep for 10 seconds.

(3) Prepare new message and back to step (1)

I don't understand how to create such thread in App Engine Backend. All I know, if I need thread, I can create it in a Backend.

I don't completely understand about explaination in Google Developer that talk about Backend. So, please help me to figure it out about its concept.

I need help. How can I create a thread in Google App Engine Backend? What files (scripts and configurations) are needed to create that project? I need a view of directory listing about it. Please give me simple example that contain one frontend and one back

Comment: Maybe this helps:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816058/web-based-multiplayer-board-card-game-toolkit/20855422#20855422

Comment: Why does this need to be done in a thread? Why not with a normal request/response cycle?

Comment: The server need to send message to all clients continuously in realtime. Request/response cycle does help me when server need to forward message from one client to another.

Answer (score 2):

OK as far as I understand it...

create a file bg_worker.yaml with the normal stuff for a module plus a handler for start and a handler for stop:

```
application: your-app 
module: bg_worker

handlers:
url: /_ah/start   
script: main.startWorker

url: /_ah/stop   
script: main.stopWorker
```

in main.startWorker start your bg thread:

```
_thread = BackgroundThread(target = work)
```

Once done you can start it by including the new yaml file in the update command,

```
appcfg -oauth2 update app.yaml bg-worker.yaml
```

Comment: why the script named with *.startWorker and *.stopWorker? Is that convention?

Comment: That is by no means convention, neither the name or the camelcasing. Use any name you like and sorry for the confusion